# Wrap method call at runtime

Tags: java

What techniques are available and advised to dynamically wrap method calls at runtime?  For example, imagine I want to wrap a call to method `foo()` with some timing information without requiring the user to alter there code at all.

Comment: Are you using JavaEE or JavaSE?

Comment: Would it change the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) for interfaces or [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) for classes.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap calls anywhere in your application, you might consider writing a simple JavaAgent. You can then use Javassist for example, to call a certain method before and/or after your method was called. The following example ads a trace call to all methods of a given class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class MethodTraceTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
        byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;

        if (className.equals("<The class you want to instrument>")) {
            try {
                byteCode = addTracer(className.replace("/", "."));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return byteCode;
    }

    private byte[] addTracer(String classname) throws NotFoundException,
        CannotCompileException, IOException {
        CtClass clazz = ClassPool.getDefault().get(classname);

        CtMethod[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (CtMethod c : methods) {
            c.insertBefore(TraceLogger.class.getName()
                    + ".get().logTrace($args);");
        }

        byte[] byteCode = clazz.toBytecode();
        clazz.detach();
        return byteCode;
    }
}
```

You can find a more extensive tutorial here: http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html

If you just want to measure the execution time of your methods, it might be easier to use something like AspectJ: http://www.pabloguerrero.org/cgblog/9/15/Monitor-Java-methods-memory-usage-and-execution-time-with-AspectJ